# error: request for member in something not a structure or union in this code

Tags: c, struct

I got the error: request for member in something not a structure or union in this code

```
int main() {
  char Oberon;

  struct Oberon {
    short borsa_oro;
    short punti_ferita;
    short incantesimi;
    short pozione_guaritrice; 
    short veleno;
    char armatura;
    char arma;
  };

  Oberon.borsa_oro=10;
  Oberon.punti_ferita=5;
  Oberon.incantesimi=2;
  Oberon.pozione_guaritrice=5;
  strcpy (Oberon.armatura, "Vesti del mago");
  strcpy (Oberon.arma, "Spada di Oberon");

  return 0;
}
```

what should I do?

Comment: 1) `char Oberon;` change to `struct Oberon Oberon;` and move to after `struct Oberon {...}`

Comment: 2) `char armatura; char arma;` --> `char armatura[32]; char arma[32];`

Comment: "*what should I do?*" have close look at the line of code the compiler's warning/error message points you to?

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant to create something like a `player` struct and then create Oberon, who is a struct player.

You also forgot to associate a block of memory to `armatura` and `arma`.

You also tried to create an instance of player before the struct was defined.

So I think what you meant was this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{

    struct player {
        short borsa_oro;
        short punti_ferita;
        short incantesimi;
        short pozione_guaritrice; 
        short veleno;
        char armatura[50];
        char arma[50];
    };

    struct player Oberon;

    Oberon.borsa_oro = 10;
    Oberon.punti_ferita = 5;
    Oberon.incantesimi = 2;
    Oberon.pozione_guaritrice = 5;
    strcpy (Oberon.armatura, "Vesti del mago");
    strcpy (Oberon.arma, "Spada di Oberon");

    printf("Oberon ha %d oro e utilizza la armatura %s\n", Oberon.borsa_oro, Oberon.armatura);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how structs should be used. You also have a char with same name `char Oberon;` remove or rename it.

Structs just describe a data-type, you still have to *initialise* them, just like any other;
example:

```
struct person {
    int age;
    ...
};

struct person p;
p.age = 10;
```

To simplify that, use typedef

```
typedef struct person {
    int age;
    ...
} person;
person p;
p.age = 10;
```